# Pyparsing extract two values without delimiter

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to make this test pass.  And I'm not sure why pyparsing isn't extracting the values as expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import (
    absolute_import,
    division,
    print_function,
    unicode_literals
)

import pytest
from pyparsing import Word, nums


def parse(text):
    value = Word(nums, max=2)

    fragment_a = (
        value
    ).setResultsName('alpha').setParseAction(lambda string,location,tokens: [int(tokens[0])])

    fragment_b = (
        value
    ).setResultsName('beta').setParseAction(lambda string,location,tokens: [int(tokens[0])])

    fragments = (
        fragment_a + fragment_b
    )

    for found in fragments.searchString(text):
        yield tuple(found)


@pytest.mark.unit
@pytest.mark.parametrize("input_text, expected_output", [
    ('1234', (12, 34)),
    ('0123', (1, 23)),
    ('0023', (0, 23)),
    ('0000', (0, 0)),
    ('506', (5, 6)),
])
def test_parse(input_text, expected_output):
    tested = False
    for output in parse(input_text):
        tested = True
        assert output == expected_output
    assert tested
```

Comment: These are passing for me. https://paste.fedoraproject.org/549745/35544914

Comment: `value = Word(nums, max=2)` should be `value = Word(nums, exact=2)`. `max=2` fails because there are more than 2 digits present. Try `fragments.runTests('1234')` to get some better output.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire So if I set it to exact=2, then the last test case, '506', won't pass.  I've added a couple extra lines to validate that an output was returned.  '506' currently doesn't match.

Comment: `value1 = Word(nums, exact=1); value2 = Word(nums, exact=2); fragments = (value2 * 2) | (value1 + value2)` - in your test, you split the 3-digit field as "5" and "06" - is there a case where you want to split it as "50" and "6"? Will you support a 2-digit field like "01"? Should this be "0" and "1", or "01" and ""? Is the "0" significant as a delimiter? I'm not trying to be difficult, but you have introduced some ambiguity here that needs ironing out. If the rules are overly complex, you might do better to just parse the whole numeric field as one, and then use a parse action to break it up.

Comment: Thanks for the questions.  I had thought about doing the latter as you mentioned... the 3 number sequence should always parse as if it was filling from the right... so 506 will always be '5' and '06' -> (5, 6).